# ¿Por qué me sale este error y cómo solucionarlo? C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start

Tags: batch

Tengo este Bat:

```
@echo off
start C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ias.exe
exit
```

me sale error **C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start** carpeta no encontrada

¿Alguien me indica cómo solucionar este error?

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba quitando `start` y añadiendo comillas dobles a la ruta.

Ejemplo:

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ias.exe"
exit
```